# PyQt4 custom widget (uic loaded) added to layout is invisible

Tags: python, widget, custom-controls, pyqt4

I've created a custom widget in pyqt4 that I've worked on and tested and now am ready to load it into my main window. Since it doesn't show up in designer, I need to manually add it to my main window manually.

My widget uses uic to load the ui file instead of converting it to a py file (it's been quicker less hassle so far) so it looks something like this:

```
class widgetWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(widgetWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("widget.ui")
    #everything else
```

now in my main class (example for brevity) I create the layout, add the widget to the layout and then add it to the main widget

```
class main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("testWindow.ui")
        mainlayout  = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        window = widgetWindow(self)
        mainlayout.addWidget(window)
        centerWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        centerWidget.setLayout(mainlayout)
        self.ui.setCentralWidget(centerWidget)
```

There are no errors thrown, and it will make space for the widget, but it simply won't show anything.

adding in the line window.ui.show() will just pop open a new window overtop the space that it should be occupying on the main window. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing some more research into the uic loader, there are two ways to load a ui file. The way I'm using it in the question is one way, the other way is with the uic.loadUiType(). This creates both the base class and the form class to be inherited by the class object instead of just the QtGui.QWidget class object.

```
widgetForm, baseClass= uic.loadUiType("addTilesWidget.ui")

class windowTest(baseClass, widgetForm):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(windowTest, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

This way, the widget can be loaded into another form as expected. As for exactly why, I haven't found that answer yet.

Some more info on the different setup types: http://bitesofcode.blogspot.com/2011/10/comparison-of-loading-techniques.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the parent argument into the loadUi statements:

```
    self.ui = uic.loadUi("widget.ui",parent)
    self.ui = uic.loadUi("testWindow.ui",self)
```

And try the following line at the end of your main class.

```
    self.setCentralWidget(centerWidget)
```

Comment: I do have the setCentralWidget, it just failed in getting copied into the question, I've updated the question with it now. Unfortunately, adding in parent/self to the loadUi doesn't do much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that 'centerWidget' is the central widget of the main window.
i.e your code for *class main* should be have a line like: 
*self.setCentralWidget(centerWidget)*

```
class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):            
        super(main, self).__init__(parent)
        ....
        self.setCentralWidget(centerWidget)
```

Comment: it was missing when I wrote up the question, but it was there in my test class. I've updated the question to reflect that.